# Code Blocks OpenCV build failed

Tags: opencv, cmake, mingw, codeblocks

Having an issue with trying to build any opencv version with code::blocks.

[image: Imgur]

I've have built opencv successfully before and have no idea what the issue is.

I've tried following many different tutorials on building opencv using mingw 4.9.2 and CMake. I have also tried using mingw32 and mingw64.

But I continue to receive the errors shown in the image above.

My question is; What is the issue? How can I fix this? And, lastly, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the version of OpenCV I was using had issues with MinGW. Tested a whole bunch of OpenCV versions (3.3, 3.2, 3.1, 2.4.13, 2.4.13.3).

I found that OpenCV version 2.4.9 with the latest version of CMake and MinGW worked.

Thought I'd leave this here to help anyone else having issues with creating OpenCV to work with MinGW/Code::Blocks